# Modifying a regex match value

Tags: c#, regex

I want to locate all image tags in my html with src not containing `http://` and prepend `http://` to the `src` attribute.

I have got the regex to find all img tags not starting with http://. I'm having some trouble appdening http:// to the src attribute alone. How can I achieve this using regex replace.

```
<img [^<]*src="(?!http://)(?<source>[^"]*)"[^<]*/>
```

Source will contain the src value. I just need it to say `$2 =  "http://" + $2`. How can I write this in c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to break existing tags, you will need to assign groups to the parts of the string you are not interested in; in order to be able to include those parts of the match in the replace pattern:

```
(<img [^<]*src=")(?!http://)(?<source>[^"]*)("[^<]*/>)
```

Then the replace is trivial:

```
regex.Replace(input, "$1http://$3$2");
```

(Also, this might work for your application use case, but I should mention, [that in general it is not considered a good idea to parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454))

Comment: its actually regex.Replace(input, "$1http://$3$2"); $2 instead of $4. You should update your answer.

Comment: Thank you. it works great. I also understood the concept of regex.replace, finally. Thanks for your help.